# Resizing fixed images inside div

Tags: html, css

Right now, if you look at my page on my computer, it will look the way I want it to look. Now if you go on a pc with higher/lower resolution, the images will move, BUT the text will stay in place, why is that?

I have tried messing around with the `position:` and height/width percentages, but haven't managed to get it to work properly yet.

I'd like to get the images to stay in one place and resize depending on the resolution.

1st:

[image]

2nd:

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="pricing">Pricing</div>
    <div><img src="images/bracket.png" class="bracket"></div>

    <div class="skills">Skills</div>
    <div><img src="images/bracket.png" class="bracket_02"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#content
{
    margin: 0% 13% auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 65%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.pricing
{
    font-size: 40;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #1eb1f5;
    position: absolute;
}

.skills
{
    font-size: 40;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 70%;
    color: #1eb1f5;
    position: absolute;
}

.bracket
{
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    position: absolute;
}

.bracket_02
{
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: 57%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I usually use `px` for everything, but I wanted to try using `%`, as I have heard it can be better for mobile for example.

Comment: Try fix the width and set text-align:center on your divs .skills and .pricing.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a very poor way of laying out pages. There are much better and more flexible methods [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/crhu6pv7/1/)**

I changed your css and html quite a lot.

1. I put the text and image in a container `.head-elem`
2. set `text-align: center` to center your text in its container
3. The `width` of the `.head-elem` to **50%**. so that it takes up 50% of the width of `#content`.
4. Made the image take of full size of its container width: `.bracket { width: 100%;}`

```css
#content { 
  width: 500px; //Change this to test out diffrent sizes
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
}
.head-elem {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1eb1f5;
}
.bracket {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="head-elem">
    <span>Pricing</span>
    <img src="http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/brackets/presentation_form_for_vertical_left_curly_bracket_uFE37_icon_256x256.png" class="bracket" />
  </div>
  <div class="head-elem">
    <span>Skills</span>
    <img src="http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/brackets/presentation_form_for_vertical_left_curly_bracket_uFE37_icon_256x256.png" class="bracket" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, but FWIW [the `center` element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Don't use it - just set `head-elem {text-align:center;}` instead. Also - it might be better to avoid the unnecessary `float:left`. I've taken the liberty of creating an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crhu6pv7/1/) for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!
Also, I appreciate the fixes @Moob

Comment: Although I cannot seem to be able to separate the 2 brackets. I'd like to have some space between them, but it won't let me.

Comment: The head elem takes 50% and there are two of them so there isent any space left. Make `width:30%;` or any value under 50%. And add margins to the two elements. margin-right on the left div and add margin -left on the right div.. I'll make a fiddle if you did'nt understand it :P

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the width in % for the class images:

```
.bracket
{
margin-top: 11%;
margin-left: 8%;
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
}

.bracket_02
{
margin-top: 11%;
margin-left: 57%;
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This worked for the brackets! Can I do the same for the text?

Comment: For font size, you will need to use media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/. The font-size won't respond like this when resizing the browser window. Instead they respond to the browser zoom/type size settings, such as if you press ctrl and + together on the keyboard in the browser.